# Continuous symbology without merging Features?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, symbology

I have a feature class with a polygon for each state. In the table there is a field attributed for specific groupings. I plan to symbolize by group.

Here's my question:

Can I make the symbology appear as if the states are merged by group without actually merging the several states into one?

The first image below shows how I would like the layer to look. Notice the continuous outline around several states. The image below that is how it looks now.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with symbol level drawing in ArcMap by carefully managing the symbol style (use a multi-layer symbol) and the symbol level drawing's Join & Merge settings (Layer Properties>Symbology>Advanced>Symbol Levels...>Turn on "Draw this layer using the symbol levels specified below" and adjust settings appropriately).

ESRI has a whole help page dedicated to an example very close to what it sounds like you are trying to do: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/map/working-with-layers/dissolving-polygon-boundaries-using-symbol-level-drawing.htm